# Finding data set for econometrics project

Tags: stock-market, data-request

I'm thinking of doing my undergrad research project on investigating the impact of happiness on stock market participation in the US stock market. However, I am struggling to find a data set. Does anyone know where I could find this data? (Data set would need to include a measure of a household's subjective wellbeing and information on whether they participate in the stock market. The data need not be in the US. I'd like data on any big economy except China, France, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands and the UK.)

Comment: Hi: you should look at academic papers that were done using households subjective well being and, separately, academic papers that were done using data regarding people's participation in the stock market. You're probably not going to find them jointly in one paper but who knows ?  Atleast if you do that search first, you could get an idea of where such data might reside. It's a very difficult thing to measure so, if it's out there,then someone in academics has probably used it.

Comment: In above, I really should have said "economics and econometrics papers" rather than academic papers. There are many different journals of both and neither is my main field so I wouldn't want to try to list them. Maybe there's an old thread out there on this site that has such a list ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe first place to look for data on participation in the stock market is the "journal of finance" which doesn't fall under either of my previously recommended categories. !!!!!!

Comment: No, I don't know, but this paper is the most relevant one I know of, 
https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.20200164